# Как записать имена загружаемых файлов в одну строку или столбец БД?

Tags: php, mysql

При использовании обычной загрузки файла(без multiple), имя файла записывается в нужный столбец в БД, но при загрузке множества файлов(с multiple) происходит запись названия только последнего файла в нужный столбец БД. Например: загрузили один файл и в БД будет результат: "img_cat_primer.png". Загрузили 2 файла,то в БД будет название только последнего загруженного файла: "img_cat_primer3", вместо "img_cat_primer2 img_cat_primer3". Как можно реализовать запись всех названий?

Вот сам код:

```
foreach($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $imgDir = "../../../img/news/";
            $imgName = "img" . "_" . $cat . "_" . time() . "_" . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"][$key]);
            $imgFile = $imgDir . $imgName;
            $imgUpload = 1;
            $imgFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if ($imgFileType != "jpg" && $imgFileType != "png" && $imgFileType != "jpeg") {
                echo "Поддерживаются только форматы: png, jpg, jpeg!";
                $imgUpload = 0;
            }

            if ($imgUpload == 0) {
                echo "Файл не был загружен.";
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key], $imgFile)) {
                    echo "Файл ". basename( $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key]). " был загружен.";
                } else {
                    echo "Ошибка при загрузке!";
                }
            }
        }

$sql = "INSERT into news (title, text, cat, pimg, img, vid, time, admin) VALUES ('$title', '$text', '$cat', '$pimgName', '$imgName', '$vidName', '$time', '$admin')";
```

Comment: Внутри цикла соберите названия файлов в массив array_push($arr, $imgFile). После цикла решите что делать с этим массивом, если вы точно уверены, что значения через разделитель в одном поле БД будет достаточно, то соберите массив implode и положите полученную строку в БД. В качестве разделителя выберите символ, который ни при каких обстоятельствах не может оказаться в именах файлов. И тут вопрос больше в том, что вы дальше будете делать с этими значениями, вполне возможно, что хранение в одном поле окажется не подходящим для дальнейшей работы и потребуется отдельная таблица

Comment: @Mike Что дальше буду делать: необходима запись названий файлов, чтоб в дальнейшем можно было удалять имена(и сами файлы) и загружать новые
Спасибо

Comment: тогда рекомендую сделать отдельную таблицу для файлов. В которой например запись: id-файла, id-новости, название файла и прочие данные по одному конкретному файлу. Тогда при записи перед циклом уже создаете новость, получаете ее id (см. last_insert_id) и в цикле по мере загрузки файлов добавляете отдельные записи в таблицу файлов. При дальнейшей работе будет гораздо проще: хотите удалить файл, удаляете с диска и ровно одну запись из БД. Не придется вытаскивать строку с именами, разбирать ее на части, удалять одно название и писать строку обратно

Comment: @Mike спасибо))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно так:

```
$Images_sql = [];
foreach($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $imgDir = "../../../img/news/";
            $imgName = "img" . "_" . $cat . "_" . time() . "_" . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"][$key]);
            $imgFile = $imgDir . $imgName;
            $imgUpload = 1;
            $imgFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if ($imgFileType != "jpg" && $imgFileType != "png" && $imgFileType != "jpeg") {
                echo "Поддерживаются только форматы: png, jpg, jpeg!";
                $imgUpload = 0;
            }

            if ($imgUpload == 0) {
                echo "Файл не был загружен.";
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key], $imgFile)) {
                    echo "Файл ". basename( $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key]). " был загружен.";
                    $Images_sql[] = $imgName;
                } else {
                    echo "Ошибка при загрузке!";
                }
            }
        }
$imgName = serialize($Images_sql);
$sql = "INSERT into news (title, text, cat, pimg, img, vid, time, admin) VALUES ('$title', '$text', '$cat', '$pimgName', '$imgName', '$vidName', '$time', '$admin')";
```